# Careers: GitHub import stuck

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, github

I added multiple projects from GitHub to my [careers profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/NEOatNHNG) but one project is stuck at “Waiting for data from GitHub...”, so it won't be displayed on my public profile.

I already tried deleting the project from the careers profile and then adding it again, but that didn't help.

Comment: @NEOatNHNG which project is stuck? I see "CAcert" and other from Google

Comment: @HackerKarma That's the strange thing: the [CAcert project](https://github.com/CAcertOrg/cacert-devel) was imported just fine, but the [CAcert root certificate installer](https://github.com/CAcertOrg/cacert-root-cert-installer) was not.

Comment: @NEOatNHNG did you tried again? Now that one is pulled, may be you can import the other one.

Comment: I'm seeing this currently—I have a number of projects that have been in this state for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like we've been hitting some GitHub API throttling over the last week, as some people have imported large numbers of repos onto their profiles. Things should be back to normal soon, so missing repos should be picked up some time in the next day or so.

In the meantime, I've gone ahead and manually approved that project on your profile so you can see it listed publicly now.

Comment: should I create another question for my profile too? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I added 2 projects [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) and [here](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms). I don't own them, but I am the lead collaborator on both. It has said "Waiting for data from GitHub" for over 3 days now.

Comment: One of mine has taken a week or so, is this normal/expected?