# Careers: "Waiting for data from GitHub"

Tags: support, jobs, github

I have added several GitHub projects to my Careers profile, but 2 of them ([1](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif), [2](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif)) are not displayed on the public profile. In edit mode, it says:

> **Waiting for data from GitHub...** This project will be hidden from your profile until we have fetched the commit data from GitHub.

I own both of these projects, but I recently transferred them to an GitHub organization I created, so they're no longer under my own account. It's the only thing that's different, all other projects are displayed without any issue.

Is this a known issue?

*EDIT: both project were eventually validated; it just took much longer than I expected*

Also, I'm unable to add [Code Cracker](https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker/) (that I don't own), even though I'm a contributor. If I try to add it by URL, it says:

> Sorry, we couldn't fetch that from GitHub: https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker/

Is this a bug, or am I not allowed to add a project that I don't own?

*EDIT: I managed to add it, by removing the final slash. Looks like a bug...*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have added several GitHub projects to my Careers profile, but 2 of
>   them ([1](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif),
>   [2](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif)) are not
>   displayed on the public profile.

Looks like the **Waiting for data from GitHub...** is over as I can see both of your GitHub repos i.e. [XamlAnimatedGif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeEaw.png) and [WpfAnimatedGif](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/265794/254554) have been successfully added to your SO Careers [profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/thomaslevesque). Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

The **Waiting for data from GitHub...** is primarily due to the commit(s) check by the contributor. As per the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244121/254554) given by Alex Warren on the post titled ['Careers should allow me to add external (authored but not owned) GitHub projects under “other”'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244121/254554). Here is what he says:

> And we check as well. When you add a repository to your profile, it
>   won't actually appear on the version employers see until we've
>   verified it. We check to see if you've actually made commits to the
>   repo before others can see it.

Also as per Dean Ward's comment:

> Just to clarify; there's no manual verification here - there's a
>   scheduled job that handles verifying GitHub repos :)

The wait issue could also be very well related to [hitting some GitHub API throttling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/265794/254554) (read answer for details). I am sure someone from SO Careers team will update in this regards.

As for the other error:

> Sorry, we couldn't fetch that from GitHub: https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker/

OP resolved it by *removing the final slash* in the above URL.

Comment: Just to clarify; there's no manual verification here - there's a scheduled job that handles verifying GitHub repos :)

Comment: Thanks Dean. I will update the answer. It was stmt. given in the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244121/254554) by Alex Warren

Comment: Thanks; indeed, I didn't wait long enough. But I don't think it's related to throttling, because the other projects where validated immediately. I suspect that for projects that are not under my own account, Careers looks at the commit to check that I am actually a contributor, and that takes time.

Comment: Regarding Code Cracker, that's exactly what I did, and I got the error mentioned in my question

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Thank you. I have updated my answer with your findings.